# Searching for Specific Column Headers in Excel File - Runtime Error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write some excel vba code that will process the content of certain columns of data.  Given the worksheet has some level of dynamic change (columns added and removed from time to time), I want my code to "find" the specific columns by their header names, and ultimately return the column number.  My File has roughly 50 columns.

The problem is this:  My code works just fine to find many of the columns (headers) I am interested in returning the column index, but some of the columns "while clearly existing", will return Nothing and thus, throws the runtime 91 error.

I can say, without a doubt that when I execute the .find, that truly, the columns DO exist (like the Comments column).  I can randomly change the failing hdr search column to a different header name, passing it to the function in the code and some columns are found just fine, and other, cause the runtime error.  I have checked the "failing" headers for special characters, blanks, LF's etc.  No luck.  Even tried re-ordering the 4 rows using FindColHdrNum function.  Again, no luck.

Was hoping fresh eyes may provide answer.  Simplified code is below which is triggered by a button on main excel worksheet.  I have not worked with functions much in VBA, and even where the function does not generate the Runtime Error, it is not returning the column value, but this is a secondary problem I can work on once I get the find code not blowing up (returning 0).

```
Sub Button119_Click()

Dim L4RankCol As Integer
Dim DecomDriverCol As Integer
Dim SupTermImpactYrCol As Integer
Dim Comments As Integer
Dim L3RankCol As Integer

    L4RankCol = FindColHdrNum("L4 Rank")   '<-- This works
    DecomDriverCol = FindColHdrNum("Decom Driver") '<-- This works
    SupTermImpactYrCol = FindColHdrNum("Support Termination Impact Yr")  '<-- This works
    Comments = FindColHdrNum("Comments")  '<-- This does not work

End Sub

Function FindColHdrNum(strHdr As String) As Integer

     Dim rngAddress As Range
     Set rngAddress = Range("Headers").Find(strHdr)
     FindColumnHdrNum = rngAddress.Column  '<--runtime error is caused by Nothing returned

End Function
```

Comment: You assign`Range("Headers")`implicit to`ActiveSheet`. Assing a Sheet explicit.  Did you check the Headers,, use Cells to define Range. Runtime error 91 is the usual behavior, because .Find() returns nothing if no match is found. So check`If Not  rngAddress Is Nothing` before you fetch Column. Have a look at the Help (oress F1 while curors pos is on member) to see the other options on .Find().

Comment: `Option Explicit`on top of every module prevents typos in member-names!

Comment: I don't have excel in-front of me, but is `Comments` a reserved word in VBA? That may be causing issues if so

Comment: Code is not working? [Debug](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) it! Step through the code and watch the values of the range. That will real what is going wrong!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher:  yes:  I have been debugging the code.  I simply have not put all my debug lines in the provided code. I am pretty experienced debugger...What we are seeing is that the correct values are pass to the function, in the function I can also see correct values passed, and in 3 out of 4 cases, .find returns what is expected, and in the fourth case, altho "comments" column absolutely exists, the find is returning "Nothing".  The questions is why is it that some clearly visible headers, in the designated range, are not found?

Comment: Ok...have found a spurious "line feed" in some of the cells.  It is as you all thought.  Just had a terrible time finding it.  Thanks all, for your help! @ComputerVersteher

Answer (score 1):

Issue turns out to be a spurious line feed that was embedded in the header.  It was strange as I kept re-typing it, but of course, I would always start at the "first letter" of the "comment" header, when in fact, the character preceded that.  Thanks to all, for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The name of your function is FindColHdrNum but you wrote this into the function:

```
FindColumnHdrNum = rngAddress.Column
```

Instead of:

```
FindColHdrNum = rngAddress.Column
```

Comment: That was fast!  Thank you Balint!  That solved the return value from the function issue. Now...if I can just figure out why some columns error out...thx again!

Comment: Are you sure that the range you call "Headers" contains all those values you are looking up? You might have the word Comments in one of the cells of top row but range Headers might refer to only A1:C1 instead of the whole row.

Comment: Thank you again, Balint!  think you had part of the answer!